# Why the dump of my linux FS is ten times smaller than FS?

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems, dump

On a linux pc, Linux Mint 17+, I dump my whole disk ("/", level 0), with the following terminal command :

```
# dump -0f /media/testuser/usbdiskblue/backup_2015MMJJ /
```

> I get a 6,3Gb file result. 
>   My disk used space size is more than 60Gb.

Why the dump of my linux FS is ten times smaller than FS ?

Comment: Did you really run this command as non-root, as indicated by the `$` prompt? In that case much of the disk was probably not readable, explaing the size difference.

Comment: I did it as root. I did not know $ means non-root sorry. @wurtel

Comment: How much space does df say is being used on that filesystem?

Comment: 60Gb, said in the begininng of dump process. But results weight is 6,3Gb. @Stephanie

Comment: Which filesystem? ext4?

Comment: @ Stephanie Yes, ext4. From ext4 to ext4.

Comment: I m trying it again right now...